# MODX Revo, как прописать чанку дополнительное поле(TV)

Tags: html, вёрстка, cms, modx

```html
<div class="col-8 offset-2 col-md-6 offset-md-0 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
    <div class="advantages__column advantages__column-[[+mod]] animate__animated"> 
        <div class="advantages__img">
            <img src="[[+img]]">
        </div>
        <h3>
            [[+longtitle]]
        </h3>
        <div>
            [[+introtext]]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

очень надеюсь если кто поможет разораться, начал изучать MODX, столкнулся с проблемой, не могу прописать чанку дополнительное поле, не работает исключительно с классами .advantages__column-[[+mod]]. С текстом, картинками все отлично. А когда пытаюсь прописать модификатор, или весь класс. Не срабатывает. Может кто знает как прописать классы через TV. Заранее благодарю.

[[pdoResources?
&parents=`6`
&depth=`0`
&tpl=`tpl-merit`
&includeTVs=`img`
&tvPrefix=``
&sortdir=`ASC`
&showHidden=`1`
]]

Comment: покажите вызов сниппета, где используете этот чанк.

Comment: [[pdoResources?
                            &parents=`6`
                            &depth=`0`
                            &tpl=`tpl-merit`
                            &includeTVs=`img`
                            &tvPrefix=`` 
                            &sortdir=`ASC`
                            &showHidden=`1`
                        ]]

Comment: Возможно нет разрешения на использование доп. поля. Проверьте разрешения

Comment: если `mod` у вас это TV поле, то в сниппете его нужно указать в параметре `&includeTVs`='img,mod'